# Implement Red5 client using Java

Tags: java, streaming, client, red5

i would like to create a client application in java that it can connect to the Red5 server and play a video. I already install the Red5 Server and I visited many sites but I can not understand how I can implement the client application. Do anyone knows some sites, formus or videos to visit for more info?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can't do it in Java. The client must be a Flash or Flex application or mobile Adobe AIR app.

Comment: Did you tried cortado applet client..? Its written for flumotion streaming server. The source code is available as opensource. You have to edit for your need  http://www.flumotion.net/cortado/

Comment: @loanna did you find a solution ?